# Preview Animation?

Tags: 3d-view

I am making an animation film and I want to see how the figures moving in realtime. But the only way for me is to render the scene. Does anyone know if there is a faster way then rendering? I do not mean things like reducing the quality (sss, tile, cliping border etc.) I already reduced time of renderin per frame to 3sec. But even if I would reduce it more, blender always needs a bit time between the frames to save the picture. So I can´t really work on my animation because just to check a 10sec of the animation I have to render 20 minutes.
Is there something like a sketch-render? :-)
How do you handle with that?

Comment: In the top header menu > View > there's a Viewport Render Animation function, you can switch to camera view, Solid mode, make sure that you've set a folder for the images, reduced the resolution %, and click on it

Comment: @moonboots Right, that's what I always try to tell people that are complaining about the playback fps in the viewport not matching the fps in the settings. The viewport is often not capable to playback in original speed. If you want to see animations in the correct speed, render a viewport animation.

Comment: This View Render Animation function is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Just so we don't miss the obvious answer, the most convenient way is just pressing play on the Playback panel, or Shift+A in the default key mapping. I assume this is not sufficient for you?

Comment: When you play it in viewport with the Playback panel you do not have realtime (if you animate more than a few cubes). It needs about the same time when you render it with "Viewport Render Animation". But after that you can watch the Viewport Render in Realtime by "Render -> View Render". It is not only "not sufficient", it was more like not possible for me to create good moves without rendering the scenes. And I am so happy to know now about the Viewport Render. I tried it earlier but did not understand what it is about because I did not realize that it is possible to watch it after rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the top header menu > *View* > there's a *Viewport Render Animation* function, you can switch to camera view, choose the *Solid* mode if the materials and lightings don't matter, make sure that you've set an output folder for the images or for the video, reduce the resolution % if needed, and click on *Viewport Render Animation*:

[image]